# how to log resulting files from Gradle build task

Tags: java, gradle

I'm trying to write a BitBucket Pipeline script for my repository, but so far without much luck, because Gradle seems a pain to debug.

**Is there any way to show the resulting files (from compiling the jar for example) in the console when it finishes the `: build` task?**

Preferably I'd like to see as much information as possible, rather too much than too little.

Adding `logging.captureStandardOutput LogLevel.DEBUG` in my `build.gradle` file didn't seem to do much, still getting the same output:

```
:compileJavaNote: -snip-\src\main\java\com\-snip-\atlas\utility\SchematicUtil.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint: deprecation for details.

:processResources
:classes
:jar
:assemble
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test UP-TO-DATE
:check UP-TO-DATE
:build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1.16 secs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it (e.g. jar for a simple Java project). The `build.gradle` is:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

jar { 
    doLast {
        new File("${buildDir}/libs").eachFileRecurse { file ->
            println "TRACER: ${file.getAbsolutePath()}"
        }
    }
}
```

It should be straight-forward to tailor for other needs.

Comment: Thank you! this did exactly what I needed it to do :) I assume I can replace `jar` with the other steps in the process if I need to debug other things?

Comment: Happy to help. re: debug other things? Well, that is a different, open-ended question. But generally, yes, you can add behaviour to other tasks.